# Jquery - Check if spans has same content but independently for every div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to check if the span has the same content as any other span. So I can add class to hide them. My goal is to keep the first one and hide the others.

Now here is the javascript that works but the result is not what I want.

```js
var itemsFound = [];
$(".myspan").each(function(index) {
  if (itemsFound.indexOf($(this).text()) > -1) {
    $(this).addClass("hide");
  } else {
    itemsFound.push($(this).text());
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="myspan">Java </span>
  <span class="myspan">Php</span>
  <span class="myspan">Python </span>
  <span class="myspan">Php </span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="myspan">Php </span>
  <span class="myspan">Java</span>
  <span class="myspan">Java </span>
  <span class="myspan">Python </span>
  <span class="myspan">Php </span>
</div>
```

The result is:

```
<div class="results">
Java
Php
Python
Php (hide)
Java (hide)
</div>

<div class="results">
Php (hide)
Java (hide)
Java (hide)
Python
Php (hide)
</div>
```

However, what I want is:

```
<div class="results">
Java
Php
Python
Php (hide)
Java (hide)
</div>

<div class="results">
Php 
Java 
Java (hide)
Python
Php (hide)
</div>
```

I also need a case insensitive solution.

Comment: (1) There is no `<span>` in your markup, (2) The `value` property is only for form controls like `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>` and `<button>` elements.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update the markup to match your code in a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a nested loop and reset the array each div

```js
$("div").each(function() {
  let arr = [];
  $(".myspan", this).each(function() {
    var value = $(this).text().trim().toUpperCase();
    if (arr.includes(value)) $(this).hide();
    else arr.push(value);
  });
});
```

```css
.show { color:red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="myspan show">Java</span>
  <span class="myspan show">Php</span>
  <span class="myspan show">Python</span>
  <span class="myspan">php</span>
  <span class="myspan">Java</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="myspan show">Php</span>
  <span class="myspan show">Java</span>
  <span class="myspan">Java</span>
  <span class="myspan show">Python</span>
  <span class="myspan">Php</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for. Meanwhile, how can we make it case insensitive? So php will also hide.

Comment: I just did using toUpperCase

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried so many times with toUpperCase and toLoweCase but could not make it work. This is what exactly I wanted. Much appreciated.